# Why is this vim plugin not getting loaded?

Tags: vim, pathogen

I am using `pathogen` to build a plugin bundle to manage my blog.  For starters I wanted to factor out some commands I defined directly in my vimrc and move them to a plugin.  Here's how I set up the bundle:

```
call pathogen#infect('/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/{}')
```

Here is a brief snippet of the beginning of the plugin:

```
echom "loaded hugo plugin"
if exists('g:loaded_hugo') || &cp || v:version < 700
  finish
endif
let g:loaded_hugo = 1

function! Tagged(tag)
  exe 'args `bin/tag-files ' . a:tag . '`'
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 Tagged call Tagged('<args>')
```

And here is the directory structure of the bundle:

```
/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/
└── hugo
    └── plugin
        └── hugo.vim

2 directories, 1 file
```

The `echom` is never getting run, and furthermore I straced a `gvim` and here is what I found matching `/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/`: (I filtered out the duplicates with `sort -u`)

```
open("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftdetect/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftplugin/html/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftplugin/markdown/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftplugin/markdown/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
open("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftplugin/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftplugin/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
open("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftplugin/vim/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/markdown/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/vim/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/vim/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
open("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 18
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/after", 0x7fffd759c6d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/autoload/ctrlp/utils.vim", 0x7fffd759a620) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/autoload/editorconfig.vim", 0x7fffd759c650) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/autoload/gitgutter/async.vim", 0x7fffd759d2f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/autoload/gitgutter/debug.vim",  <unfinished ...>
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/autoload/gitgutter/diff.vim", 0x7fffd759e6d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/autoload/gitgutter/sign.vim", 0x7fffd75a0040) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/autoload/htmlcomplete.vim", 0x7fffd759c4c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/filetype.vim", 0x7fffd759f830) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftoff.vim", 0x7fffd759f830) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftplugin/html.vim", 0x7fffd759cf40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftplugin/html.vim", 0x7fffd759d050) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftplugin/html.vim", 0x7fffd759d270) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftplugin/markdown.vim", 0x7fffd759da70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftplugin/markdown.vim", 0x7fffd759dda0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftplugin/markdown.vim",  <unfinished ...>
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftplugin/vim.vim", 0x7fffd759e6e0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftplugin/vim.vim", 0x7fffd759e830) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/ftplugin/vim.vim",  <unfinished ...>
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/indent/markdown.vim", 0x7fffd759da70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/indent/markdown.vim", 0x7fffd759db80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/indent/markdown.vim", 0x7fffd759dda0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/indent/vim.vim", 0x7fffd759e830) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/indent/vim.vim",  <unfinished ...>
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/scripts.vim", 0x7fffd75a0060) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/css.vim", 0x7fffd759ae20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/css.vim", 0x7fffd759af30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/css.vim", 0x7fffd759b150) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/html.vim", 0x7fffd759b9e0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/html.vim", 0x7fffd759baf0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/html.vim", 0x7fffd759bd10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/javascript.vim", 0x7fffd759ae20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/javascript.vim", 0x7fffd759af30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/javascript.vim", 0x7fffd759b150) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/markdown.vim", 0x7fffd759c510) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/markdown.vim", 0x7fffd759c620) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/markdown.vim", 0x7fffd759c840) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/pod.vim", 0x7fffd759b230) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/pod.vim", 0x7fffd759b380) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/vb.vim", 0x7fffd759ae20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/vb.vim", 0x7fffd759af30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/vb.vim", 0x7fffd759b150) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/vim.vim", 0x7fffd759d2d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/syntax/vim.vim",  <unfinished ...>
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/vimfiles", 0x7fffd759cce0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo/vimfiles/after", 0x7fffd759c750) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Clearly it found the `hugo` plugin directory, it just never even tried looking in the related `plugin` subdirectory.

What am I missing here?

**Update**: Here's the current value of `&rtp`:

```
/home/frew/code/blog/etc/vim-bundle/hugo,/home/frew/.vim,/home/frew/.vim/bundle-lua/neocomplete,/home/frew/.vim/
bundle-python/editorconfig,/home/frew/.vim/bundle-python/ultisnips,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/FastFold,/home/frew/.v
im/bundle/IndentAnything,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/airline,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/better-whitespace,/home/frew/.vim
/bundle/colors-solarized,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/commentary,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/csv,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/ctr
lp,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/denite,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/eunuch,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/exchange,/home/frew/.vim/b
undle/fugitive,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/fugitive-gitlab,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/gitgutter,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/go
,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/goyo,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/inkpot,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/l9,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/last
place,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/lost,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/matchit,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/matchmaker,/home/frew/.v
im/bundle/obsession,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/pathogen,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/perl,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/projectio
nist,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/python,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/quick-scope,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/repeat,/home/frew/.
vim/bundle/sleuth,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/splitjoin,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/surround,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/tabula
r,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/terminus,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/textobj-between,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/textobj-entire,/
home/frew/.vim/bundle/textobj-underscore,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/textobj-user,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/unimpaired,/
home/frew/.vim/bundle/vinegar,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/visual-star-search,/home/frew/.vim/bundle/wipeout,/var/lib/
vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim80,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,
/home/frew/.vim/bundle/tabular/after,/home/frew/.vim/bundle-python/ultisnips/after,/home/frew/.vim/after
```

Comment: I assume you already checked the permissions on the hugo `plugin` directory, but it's worth double-checking.  (sorry if this is too trivial, but it's like an "is it plugged in?" question, you have to rule out simple stuff first.)

Comment: 775 for the directories, 664 for the file.

Comment: seems right.  I guess the next thing I would try to figure out is what's causing all of those `open` and `stat` calls that return -1 (no such file or directory).  The process of loading/finding the plugin could be getting derailed by those.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim Pope answered this question on github.  Plugins get loaded before sessions, so modifying `&rtp` at session time is too late if you want to load plugins.